# When import Maatwebsite/excel 3.1 xlsx file in laravel 10 shows error

Tags: postman, maatwebsite-excel, laravel-10

```
Exception: Could not find zip member zip://D:\resolv_new\resolv_v2\backend\storage\framework\cache\laravel-excel\laravel-excel-1vH2iciofDVglNHgp5Ty4T93ZFQZEQjr.xlsx#_rels\.rels in file D:\resolv_new\resolv_v2\backend\app\Http\Controllers\ImportController.php on line 89

#0 D:\resolv_new\resolv_v2\backend\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Controller.php(54): App\Http\Controllers\ImportController->upload(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#1 D:\resolv_new\resolv_v2\backend\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher.php(43): Illuminate\Routing\Controller->callAction('upload', Array)
#2 D:\resolv_new\resolv_v2\backend\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Route.php(259): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(App\Http\Controllers\ImportController), 'upload')
#3 D:\resolv_new\resolv_v2\backend\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Route.php(205): Illuminate\Routing\Route->runController()
#4 D:\resolv_new\resolv_v2\backend\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(799): Illuminate\Routing\Route->run()
#5 D:\resolv_new\resolv_v2\backend\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(141): Illuminate\Routing\Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#6 D:\resolv_new\resolv_v2\backend\app\Http\Middleware\SessionHandler.php(27): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#7 D:\resolv_new\resolv_v2\backend\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(180): App\Http\Middleware\SessionHandler->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#8 D:\resolv_new\resolv_v2\backend\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings.php(50): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#9 D:\resolv_new\resolv_v2\backend\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#10 D:\resolv_new\resolv_v2\backend\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests.php(159): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#11 D:\resolv_new\resolv_v2\backend\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests.php(125): Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests->handleRequest(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure), Array)
#12 D:\resolv_new\resolv_v2\backend\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests.php(87): Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests->handleRequestUsingNamedLimiter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure), 'api', Object(Closure))
#13 D:\resolv_new\resolv_v2\backend\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure), 'api')
#14 D:\resolv_new\resolv_v2\backend\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(116): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#15 D:\resolv_new\resolv_v2\backend\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(798): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#16 D:\resolv_new\resolv_v2\backend\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(777): Illuminate\Routing\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#17 D:\resolv_new\resolv_v2\backend\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(741): Illuminate\Routing\Router->runRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route))
#18 D:\resolv_new\resolv_v2\backend\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(730): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#19 D:\resolv_new\resolv_v2\backend\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(200): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#20 D:\resolv_new\resolv_v2\backend\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(141): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#21 D:\resolv_new\resolv_v2\backend\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#22 D:\resolv_new\resolv_v2\backend\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull.php(31): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#23 D:\resolv_new\resolv_v2\backend\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#24 D:\resolv_new\resolv_v2\backend\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#25 D:\resolv_new\resolv_v2\backend\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings.php(40): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#26 D:\resolv_new\resolv_v2\backend\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#27 D:\resolv_new\resolv_v2\backend\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#28 D:\resolv_new\resolv_v2\backend\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#29 D:\resolv_new\resolv_v2\backend\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance.php(86): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#30 D:\resolv_new\resolv_v2\backend\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#31 D:\resolv_new\resolv_v2\backend\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Http\Middleware\HandleCors.php(62): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#32 D:\resolv_new\resolv_v2\backend\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\Http\Middleware\HandleCors->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#33 D:\resolv_new\resolv_v2\backend\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies.php(39): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#34 D:\resolv_new\resolv_v2\backend\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#35 D:\resolv_new\resolv_v2\backend\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(116): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#36 D:\resolv_new\resolv_v2\backend\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(175): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#37 D:\resolv_new\resolv_v2\backend\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(144): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#38 D:\resolv_new\resolv_v2\backend\public\index.php(51): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
```

This is my Controller code

```
/*Upload Claim CSV file and Upload Data into DB*/
    public function upload(Request $request)
    {
        try {
            $practice_dbid = $request->get('practice_dbid');
            $savedata = $request->file('file_name');
            $filenames = $request->file('file_name')->getClientOriginalName();
            $user = $request->get('user_id');
            $unique_name = md5($filenames . time());
            $filename = date('Y-m-d') . '_' . $filenames;
            $path = "../uploads";
            $savedata->move($path, $unique_name);
            $path = "../uploads/" . $unique_name;
            $report_date = $request->get('report_date');
            $notes = $request->get('notes');


            Excel::import(new ImportClaims, $filenames);
            // Excel::import(new ImportClaims, $request->file('file_name')->store('files'));

            // Excel::import($importClaims, $filenames);
            Log::info('upload checking');
            // Log::debug(print_r($importClaims, true));

            return response()->json([
                // 'message' =>  $importClaims,
                'upload_msg'  => "Upload Complete"
            ]);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Log::debug($e->getMessage() . $e->getLine());
            throw new Exception($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

When laravel 10 form insert maatwebsite/excel import working fine.,

But hit the API call shows above error.., how to fix it?

Comment: it would be better if you could show us what you wrote on your code

Comment: I have mentioned above controller code, comment line code also tried, When hit API call only not working. If web.php call normal form submission working fine